# Locking scroll of one div while viewing another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a site that is in essence a single page site.

There is a masonry grid of images which when an item is clicked a detail 'panel' slides in from the left and when this panel is closed it slides out and the grid slides back in.

However, when the grid comes back it has reset the scroll so the user would need to start from the top again and when the grid will contain 100s of items this could prove to be a pain.

I've been trying to cache the scrollTop of the grid div and then apply this to the panel close button so the grid will return to it's original place when it comes back into view. It didn't seem to work unless there was a timeout added to the function but this isn't the effect I'm after.

It'd be great to be able to lock the grid div while the panel is shown and then unlock it once it's back in view, is there anything that might do that?

I've put a basic fiddle of the structure here http://jsfiddle.net/kxdy3bb5/2/

```
var $workItems = $(' #workLinks > li '),
    $sectionWork = $(' #workSection '),
    $workPanelsContainer = $('#panels'),
    $workPanels = $workPanelsContainer.children('div'),
    $closeWorkItem = $('div#closeBtn');


// clicking on a work item to show 
$workItems.on('click', function (event) {

    // scale down main section
    $sectionWork.addClass('slide-out');

    // show panel for this work item
    var $panel = $workPanelsContainer.find("[data-panel='" + $(this).data('panel') + "']");
    currentWorkPanel = $panel.index();
    $panel.addClass('show-panel');
});

// Close current work item and bring back the list
$closeWorkItem.on('click', function (event) {

    var $currentPanel = $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel);

    // alert("THIS WORKS");
    $sectionWork.removeClass('slide-out');
    $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel).removeClass('show-panel');
    $('.workWrapper').scrollTop(1000);

});
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `overflow:hidden` for the `body,html` elements. That will hide the scrollbar and disable the scrolling of the site.

Comment: Your fiddle looks to be working fine in Chrome and I don't see a timeout. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, unfortunately some of the panel elements will need to be scrollable. Plus it still reset the grid to the top.

ReLeaf, I removed the timeout because it's not the solution I am after. If you scroll to img5, click to show the panel and then click the black square 'back button' the item list is rest to the top, whereas I'd like it to stay at the position it was when you clicked img5, if that makes sense?

A fiddle with the timeout included is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/kxdy3bb5/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily control the scrollbar position using JS properties `scrollTop` and `scrolLeft`, but your case is a bit different due to the transitions, you can only set the `scrollTop` to the last position after the transition is complete and list is back in scene, so you should use `transitionend` event.

```
$sectionWork.on('webkitTransitionEnd', function(e){
if(!$(this).hasClass('slide-out') && bodyScrollTop){
    document.body.scrollTop = bodyScrollTop;
}
```

Take a look on this http://jsfiddle.net/e8zb31j2/1/

OR

Instead of using the body scrollbar you can use the div scrollbar and nothing else is required. Just add properties `height` and `overflow-y`:

```
#workSection {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8zb31j2/3/

Comment: Thank you Luizgrs. There is still a little 'jump' as the list transitions back in. I'm trying to get it to look as though the list hasn't moved when it comes back into view. If this isn't possible I think I'll have to look for another solution/transition.

Comment: If the panel came in from the bottom rather than the left would that make any difference or is it the same principle? Would removing the list transition help, so the panel just floats over the top of it rather than 'pushing' it out to the right?

Comment: note you're using the scrollbar of the body, if you use the scrollbar from sectionWork instead, you would not have this issue,

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the timeout:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxdy3bb5/6/

```
 $(window).scrollTop( scrollTopRestore );
```

Comment: Cheers Digital Illusion but if you scroll to img5 in the list, click and then go back, the list is reset to the top not at the position you left it.

Comment: on chrome you need as well  .workWrapper {   position: relative; } I've updated the fiddle